# Encrypt and backup files directly to cloud storage? (No locally saved copies)

Tags: encryption, backup, cloud-storage, synchronization

So far I know of the following services:

- Tresorit (paid cloud storage service)
- SpiderOak (paid cloud storage service)
- Arq (paid software, works with a number of cloud services)

...are there any others?

Specifically, I am talking about Type 1 architecture as mentioned at http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/selecting-encryption-method-cloud-storage.htm